# AES_DECRYPT in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, encryption

I still dont get how to implement an AES_DECRYPT in a WHERE clause.

So far I have:

```
SELECT id, AES_DECRYPT("name","salt"), AES_DECRYPT("address","salt") FROM members WHERE name = AES_DECRYPT("Hans","salt") OR address = AES_DECRYPT("Street","salt")
```

What I want to achieve is to get the row if either name OR address field is having a value.
how can i do this with AES_DECRYPT?

thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.
It needs to be AES_ENCRYPT in the WHERE clause rather than AES_DECRYPT.